# gettext seems not working

Tags: php, gettext

Im using xampp on c://xampp and trying to implement gettext but it isnt wokring. FUnction activated in php.ini and tested if function_exists
my folder structure is:

- htdocs

  - FeedReader

    - PHP located here
    - locale

      - de_AT

        - LC_MESSAGES

          - de_AT.mo
          - de_AT.po

The PHP:

```
putenv("LANG=de_AT");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_AT");
bindtextdomain("de_AT", "locale");
textdomain("de_AT");

echo gettext("test");
```

it always prints "test" and not the translation, i think there is a routing problem in bindtexdomain. i tried different stuff like "../locale" but that didnt work.

Comment: Try putting the absolute filepath into `bindtextdomain`; e.g. *C://xampp/htdocs/FeedReader/locale*

Comment: @CD001 doesnt work, already tried that too

Comment: @CD001 seems like its working, but i need to restart apache, i think thats beacuse of caching.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you have to restart Apache whenever you change a .po file as they're loaded in at startup.